# How do I reverse the order in PHP when Echoing

Tags: php, echo, reverse

The goal here is to reverse the echoed php results so that the very first is the very last number.

I want the weeks to go 3-1 instead of 1-3 but for new posts to follow as well.

```
 <?php
/* Get posts for home page */
      if(is_page_template('template-home.php')):

      $args = array(
        'post_type'=>'post'
    );

    if(is_front_page()){
        $args['paged'] = get_query_var('page');
        global $paged;
        $paged = $args['paged'];
    } else {
        $args['paged'] = get_query_var('paged');
    }

    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

    endif;
?>

 <div id="scroll-menu" class="scroll-menu"> <span class="week">WEEK</span>
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) :  $i=0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $i++; ?>

     <div id="scroll-post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"            class="scroll-post">
    <span><?php echo $i; ?></span>
    <div class="scroll-menu-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

 <?php endif;?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: data coming from db? set the sort order

Comment: Or if not, use a for loop and decrement instead of increment.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type'=>'post'
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'orderby' => 'date'
);
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, check www.echomagonline.com
It still is the same order  I also tried swaping ASC with DESC and still nothing ;[